# Remove closest points in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, for example, A and B. A is a master array and B is a child array. A and B both contain centroid points or `x` and `y' values. I want to remove all the closest points of B from A. For more clarity, for each element of B you find the closest element in A and remove it.

Any help will be highly appreciated. I am new to JavaScript.

Please find the example below for clarity.

```js
const A = [{
    x: 58,
    y: 62.60,
  },
  {
    x: 52,
    y:196,
  },
  {
    x: 167,
    y: 143.601,
  },
  {
    x:178,
    y: 183,
  },
];

const B = [{
    x: 57,
    y: 61.60,
  },
  {
    x: 50,
    y:196,
  },
];
```

**Expected Answer:**

```js
const A = [{
        x: 167,
        y: 143.601,
      },
      {
        x:178,
        y: 183,
      },
    ];
```

Comment: A is not just one point, it's many points. So how do you define which point in B is closest to A? Do you mean to compare the corresponding entries in the two arrays?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I want to compare X and Y values of two points. I just added example arrays.

Comment: I don't understand. A has 4 points, B has 2 points. Which do you compare?

Comment: @Barmar A is a master array and B is a child array. I want to remove the closest points of B from A. I hope its clear.

Comment: So for each element of B, you find the closest element in A and remove it?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're correct.

Comment: from what radial distance limit are the points considered close or not? 
and where is the code you tried to solve this?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? Write a function to calculate the distance. Then for each element of B, loop through `A`, calculate the distance, and see if it's smaller than the current smallest distance. If it is, update the smallest distance and its index. At the end of the loop, remove the item at the index. Repeat this for all elements of B.

Comment: @MisterJojo I think he means the Euclidean distance between A[i] and B[j]

Comment: @Barmar I am new to Javascript with limited knowledge on programming. Could you please help me with the code?

Comment: @MisterJojo Barmar is right. Euclidean distance between A[i] and B[j]

Comment: OK, but which distance ?

Comment: @Bz1432 I'm not sure how to help you without just writing it for you. I tried to describe it to you, what more can I do?

Comment: @MisterJojo Euclidean distance.

Comment: I would prefer that you indicate the maximum **VALUE** of this Euclidean distance rather than repeating to myself 3 times that it is a Euclidean distance!

Comment: @MisterJojo It's something that needs to be calculated between each element of the two arrays. For each element of B, you calculate the distance to each element of A. Then you remove the element of A where this distance is smallest.

Comment: @Barmar so, if `A=[{x:1,y:1}]` and `B=[{x:10000000,y:10000000}]`  this two coordinates are closest just because B and A have each one only one coordinate...

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes, that seems like a limiting case.

Comment: In fact, whenever `A.length <= B.length`, it will remove everything from `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the problem into smaller parts.

First, write a function to check the distance between 2 points.

```js
const distance = (a, b) => {
    return Math.hypot(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
};
```

Then write a function to find the position of the smallest distance in a list of points, given a target point.

```js
const findClosestIndex = (list, point) => {
    const distances = list.map((listPoint) => {
        return distance(listPoint, point);
    });
    const min = Math.min(...distances);
    return distances.findIndex((p) => {
        return p === min;
    });
};
```

Finally, remove all the points that you want to remove.

```js
const A = [
    { x: 58, y: 62.6 },
    { x: 52, y: 196 },
    { x: 167, y: 143.601 },
    { x: 178, y: 183 },
];

const B = [
    { x: 57, y: 61.6 },
    { x: 50, y: 196 },
];

const AWithClosestToBRemoved = B.reduce((result, point) => {
    const closestIndex = findClosestIndex(result, point);
    return result.filter((_, i) => {
        return i !== closestIndex;
    });
}, A);
```

##### Edit History

- Changed more verbose math into `Math.hypot` based on suggestion in comments.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot

Comment: Using `filter()` to remove by index is strange, you can just use `splice()`.